# AES with salt from java to PHP get different result

Tags: java, php, aes

I had issue when converting AES encryption from java to php, it show different value result in php, that should show the exact value from java

Java

```
public class AesUtil {
    private final Cipher cipher;
    public final static String passPhrase = "";
    public final static String IV = ""; //32bit IV Lenght
    public final static  String SALT = "";
    public final static int KEY_SIZE = 128;
    public final static int ITERATION_COUNT = 10000;

    public AesUtil() {
        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            throw fail(e);
        }
    }
    //Call this function to encrypt some String
    public String encrypt(String passPhrase, String plaintext) {
        try {
            SecretKey key = generateKey(SALT, passPhrase);



            byte[] encrypted = doFinal(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, IV, plaintext.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            return base64(encrypted);

        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            throw fail(e);
        }
    }

    private byte[] doFinal(int encryptMode, SecretKey key, String iv, byte[] bytes) {
        try {
            cipher.init(encryptMode, key, new IvParameterSpec(hex(IV)));
            return cipher.doFinal(bytes);
        }
        catch (InvalidKeyException
                | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
                | IllegalBlockSizeException
                | BadPaddingException e) {
            throw fail(e);
        }
    }

    private SecretKey generateKey(String salt, String passphrase) {
        try {
            SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
                KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(passphrase.toCharArray(), hex(salt), ITERATION_COUNT, KEY_SIZE);
            SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(factory.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded(), "AES");
            return key;
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            throw fail(e);
        }
    }

    public static String random(int length) {
        byte[] salt = new byte[length];
        new SecureRandom().nextBytes(salt);
        return hex(salt);
    }

    public static String base64(byte[] bytes) {
        return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(bytes));
    }

    public static byte[] base64(String str) {
        return Base64.decodeBase64(str.getBytes());
    }

    public static String hex(byte[] bytes) {
        return Hex.encodeHexString(bytes);
    }

    public static byte[] hex(String str) {
        try {
            return Hex.decodeHex(str.toCharArray());
        }
        catch (DecoderException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }
    private IllegalStateException fail(Exception e) {
        return new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
}
```

this is my code in php version,

```
<?php
    $password = "";
        $salt = "";
        $iv = ""; //32bit IV Lenght
        $length = 16;
        $salt = "";
        $interation = 10000;
    
        $key1 = mb_convert_encoding($password, "UTF-8");
        $bytes = openssl_pbkdf2($key1, $salt, $length, $interation, "sha1");
    
        $bytes2 = hash_pbkdf2("sha1", $password, $salt, $interation, $length, true);
    
    
        $ciphertext_b64 = base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($plaintext,"aes-128-cbc", $bytes2,OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv));

?>
```

Please tell me how to solve this problem, if you have any suggestion in different programming language it's no problem, thank you

Comment: The PHP code is missing the hex decoding of IV and salt. By the way, a static salt and a static IV are insecure.

Comment: thank you for the reply, i was add hex for iv but the result is still different. and salt, iv static from document API

Comment: *... i was add hex for iv but...*: The hex decoding in the PHP code must be done for IV **and** salt (in the Java code both are hex decoded as well!). After this fix, both codes return the same ciphertext on my machine. If it still doesn't work for you, please edit your question and post test data.

Comment: I couldn’t have done it without you